# How to get Shared preferences value from another activity?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using shared preferences in one activity to store user_id and name. I want to take user_id from another activity. I can Get the value from First activity, but i cant get it from another activity.
What changes needs to make for this?

Define

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = LoginActivityMerchant.this.getSharedPreferences(config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                            //Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                            //Adding values to editor
                            editor.putBoolean(config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
                            editor.putString(config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, user);
                            editor.putString("UserId",response.toString());
                            config.KEY_USERNAME = user;

                            //Saving values to editor
                            editor.commit();
```

Call

```
 final SharedPreferences SharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences("LoginActivityMerchant",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String Userid=SharedPreferences.getString("UserId", "");
```

Comment: Simply re-read the preference value. It does not change between Activities.

Comment: how to get the value?

Comment: The way you're doing. But I'd choose a different name for the created object. i.e.: `final SharedPreferences prefs ...` and then `prefs.getString(...`

Answer (score 1):

The preferences you are using are very likely different ones.

Make sure that you have the same values for the first parameter in this call

```
getSharedPreferences(config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and

```
getSharedPreferences("LoginActivityMerchant",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

this will only work if `config.SHARED_PREF_NAME` equals `"LoginActivityMerchant"`, and I'm guessing it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you...It was my mistake

Comment: @proversion I see you have never accepted an answer. The way we work on SO is that if you receive an answer that solves your issue, you accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. This indicates that your problem is solved and can be used as token of appreciation to the people who help you

Answer (score 0):

```
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

     //get string 
     String value = mSharedPreferences.getString("VAL", "Null")
```

You can open SharedPreferences anywhere in application

Answer (score -1):

To **edit** data from shared preference

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("text", mSaved.getText().toString());
 editor.putInt("selection-start", mSaved.getSelectionStart());
 editor.putInt("selection-end", mSaved.getSelectionEnd());
 editor.apply();
```

To **retrieve** data from shared preference

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 

  int selectionStart = prefs.getInt("selection-start", -1);
  int selectionEnd = prefs.getInt("selection-end", -1);
```

Above is simple example, apply this in your code :)

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: `getPreferences` only works with the current Activity context, doesn't it? It's not shared between Activities?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes indeed, it's private for the calling activity